# Фрагменты теперь deprecated?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Как я понял с Android P фрагменты deprecated. С чем это связано и что использовать вместо них?

Comment: ух вы меня и напугали :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Прямо первой строкой [официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html?hl=ru) написано:

> This class was deprecated in API level P.
>   Use the Support Library Fragment for consistent behavior across all devices and access to Lifecycle.

Что значит, что использовать нужно фрагменты из библиотеки поддержки[`Support.v4.Fragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html?hl=ru) и связано это с обеспечением совместимости с новой фичей гугл, под названием [Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/index.html) (куда входит и класс [`Lifecycle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Lifecycle.html?hl=ru)), а так же для однообразного поведения на всех возможных устройствах.